# Bluetooth em emulador

Tags: react-native, bluetooth

Estou querendo saber se é possível ligar um bluetooth em algum emulador, pois, estou fazendo um projeto que precisa testar o bluetooth e eu não tenho um smartphone Android e eu gostaria de saber se tem como emular um bluetooth que o emulador consiga encontrar, estou usando o Genymotion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não é possível com Genymotion e Android Studio! O Genymotion não possui a funcionalidade Bluetooth em seu aplicativo desktop, como mostra a [documentação](https://www.genymotion.com/desktop/). Também não é possível emular essa funcionalidade no emulador do Android Studio.

[Limitações do emulador do Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator#limitations)

Em uma breve pesquisa, encontrei o [Android x86](https://www.android-x86.org/) que possui a funcionalidade de Bluetooth.